# Manual crop not working in Chrome

Tags: media

Is anyone using manualcrop https://drupal.org/project/manualcrop?
It works fine in Firefox but doesn't work in Chrome.

Using Drupal 7.

Thanks!

Comment: I use version 1.6 (bootstrap sub-theme) and i have no problems at all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there were an issue for that on DO: https://drupal.org/node/2093533

Comment: It is an issue of manual crop:
https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/manualcrop?text=chrome&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All

specially: https://www.drupal.org/project/manualcrop/issues/2348859

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue queue going on drupal.org for this - https://drupal.org/node/2093533

It looks like the module maintainer may have fixed the chrome issue with the latest dev version